# Windows 10 Xbox App missing advanced settings

Tags: windows-10

Edit: to anyone who found this question through a search, I never did find a solution for this for **version 1607**.  Microsoft's documentation was apparently incorrect and a newer version was needed to give access to the additional settings.

Version 1607 is now long past end of life so if you are reading this you probably should keep looking for a more recent question.

---

Using Windows 10 Pro, version 1607 build 14393.1715 and Xbox App 31.32.11001.00000, on a desktop with KB + mouse not in tablet mode.  This is a 2017 model Acer PC with 17-7700 and nvidia GTX 1060.  This is English-US Pro with a valid license key, upgraded from the Home English-US version that came installed on the Acer.

I want to adjust the DVR settings that I see in posts here and on Microsoft's site, but when I go to Settings > Game DVR the only setting I see is:

Record game clips and screenshots using Game DVR  ( off / on )

The three settings I am most interested in are: Saving Captures (see/set folder), Audio (quality setting), Video encoding (resolution, quality).  According to the support.xobx.com page those should all exist.

https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/social/adjust-game-dvr-settings-windows-10

Note that in Win10 1607 the main Windows > Settings has no Gaming or Game DVR sections at all, the only settings are in the app itself.

Am I somehow in some limited tablet view of the app?  Are the other settings only available for newer versions of Windows 10?  As far as I can tell there is no way to update the Xbox App manually or even to know whether an update exists.

Xbox App > Settings > Game DVR:
[image: Xbox App > Settings > Game DVR]

Comment: Can you provided specifics about which DVD settings you expect to see **exactly**? "Are the other settings only available for newer versions of Windows 10?" - There is a good chance this is the case, update your question, and update your question your question can be answered.

Comment: **Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail** to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you perhaps running a K/N version of Windows 10?  At the very least, the video quality options should exist since they are only available if you are running 1607+

Comment: @Ramhound : It's Windows 10 Pro English - US, upgraded from from Windows 10 Home English-US installed on the Acer, using a legit key from my MSDN/Visual Studio subscription.

Comment: You are positive that you are running 1607?  I ask you to verify this again, because again, the video quality option only exist in 1607+.

Comment: @Ramhound : About Your PC says Edition: Pro, Version: 1607.

Comment: Is there a reason, say for instances comparability concerns, you have not already installed 1703 after 7 months?  I am not saying it will be fixed in 1703 but it might.

Comment: I have not denied or delayed the upgrade.  I've been waiting for Windows Update to decide to do it on its own since some users forcing the upgrade have had issues.

Comment: 1703 was released to all compatible systems months ago. Are you sure you haven't deferred the update?

Comment: So I assume your Game DVR does not look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHAYB.png)? Please provide a screenshot, using the built-in snipping tool in window mode, and provide a link to the screenshot to i.stack.imgur for comparison reasons.

Comment: Yeah, despite what the article says, it only applies to 1703+ unless your not looking at the correct location cause your looking at the Xbox application not Settings -> Gaming (which is 1703+)

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to open windows, open Xbox, navigate to settings, then click 'Game DVR' then was redirected to an obscure Game DVR settings page to make these adjustments.

You can't type Game DVR in settings and find it however you can Type Game to find the Game Bar settings, the Game DVR settings are just below that. Good luck, that was with Windows 10 version 1709

Comment: Properly composed text always sounds better and I think your answer has not sufficient information what the OP was looking for. Better re-create it and illustrate in proper order or refer this link,, https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer.